# How to Determinate the path cMessage in Omnet++?

Tags: omnet++

I created a small network topology in Omnet++ and the red pointer(cMessage) is working normally from device to another device etc , but I want to modify for example Router device that (if cMessage come in to Router device from its input interface01 , send cMessage or emit cMessage from its output interface02 to another device).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use `getArrivalGate()` to determine a gate on which message arrived. An example:

```
cGate * gate = msg->getArrivalGate();
if (gate->isName("interface01")) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: I used it and it is working correctly .
Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. Could you mark the answer as correct (the green check image)? It helps others.